# Create tables with Many-to-One relation in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am a newbie with Postgresql and database . I have the following table Shop

```
Create table Shop( 
id integer ,
Name varchar(50),
Adress varchar(50) )
```

And I have a second table Product

```
Create table Product( 
id integer ,
Name varchar(50),
Price float)
```

How to create a relation One-To-One between Product and Shop ?

Comment: You use both one-to-one and many-to-one and I assume you want many-to-many. That's the one you want if every product can be available in multiple shops and shops can have multiple products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a separate table, called a junction table or join table (and unfortunately has many other names)

```
CREATE TABLE Products_in_shop (
   shop_id INTEGER,
   product_id INTEGER
)
```

You can then `JOIN` them for specific queries, e.g. the products a specific shop carries:

```
SELECT p.Name
FROM Shop AS s
JOIN Products_in_shop AS pis ON pis.shop_id = s.id
JOIN Product AS p ON pis.product_id = p.id
WHERE s.Name = 'MyShop'
```